# How to resolve method 'setText(java.lang.String)

Tags: android, android-studio, set, java

I know this has been posted countless times and im sorry but I have tried to follow the solutions but can't seem to fix it.

Basically I'm trying to read records from Android SQLite Database, but I keep getting the error at `setText`.

```
public class Landing extends AppCompatActivity{

    public Button buttonProducts;

    public void countRecords(){

        int recordCount = new TableControllerAppointments(this).count();

        ScrollView textViewRecordCount = findViewById(R.id.textViewRecordCount);
        textViewRecordCount.setText(recordCount + " records found.");

    }
```

I'm following a tutorial and I added this code to my XML file,

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/textViewRecordCount"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:padding="1dp"
    android:text="@string/textViewRecordCount"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.182"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/buttonCreateAppointment"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.146" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayoutRecords"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Sorry if im not posting right this is my first time. I think its something to do with my ScrollView but not sure, any help would be much appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code, XML, or logcat output. Please post all text as text.

Comment: Why setting text on ScrollView. Text is set on TextView

Comment: Ok sorry i have corrected it there now, cheers

Comment: ScrollView does not have any text. It is not designed to show text, and that's why it doesn't have a `setText` method. It's like you were trying to fly on the car, and wondering why it doesn't want to fly.

Answer (score 0):

> How to resolve method 'setText(java.lang.String)

**FYI**

[**`setText()`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText(char[],%20int,%20int))  is method of [**`textview`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html) not a method of **`Scrollview`** because `ScrollView` does not have any `setText()`

You can not use as `Scrollview.setText("Nilesh");`

```
textview.setText("Nilesh");
```

Comment: In regards to my XML where i have implemented Scrollview, is there a method i use for Scrollview

Comment: @AaronSmith no u can't use `setText()`  method to Scrollview

Answer (score 0):

It must be like this I hope

```
public Button buttonProducts;
    public void countRecords(){
        int recordCount = new TableControllerAppointments(this).count();

        TextView textViewRecordCount = findViewById(R.id.textViewRecordCount);
        textViewRecordCount.setText(String.ValueOf(recordCount) + " records found.");
}
```

You can't set text to Scrollview, first you have to understand this, it's basic

Comment: Sorry im quite new to this at the moment, thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to set text for "Scrollview", which is absolutely wrong. Scroll view is a view which is using for scroll the layout while the application runs. to full fill your requirement you have to declare a TextView. Then you can set the text for it.